# How to run playbook after creating ec2 with ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I have playbook to create ec2 like this

```
- name: Create an EC2 Instance
  hosts: localmachine
  connection: local
  vars_files:
    - vars/common.yml
  roles:
     - ec2
```

Now I also want that after the ec2 is created then I want to run another role inside that ec2 machine. I know how to wait for ec2 to be created but I don't know how to run role in newly created ec2.

This is how I wait for it

```
- name: Wait for instances to listen on port 22
  wait_for:
    state: started
    host: "{{ ec2_info.instances[0].private_ip" }}"
    port: 22
  when: ec2_info|changed
```

but I want another task after that to run different roles inside that ec2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a detailed AWS guide with [a section on provisioning](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_aws.html#provisioning).  The short answer is that you should register the results of your provisioning into a variable (it looks like you've already chosen `ec2_info` for this) and then add those into another group:

```
   - name: Add all instance public IPs to host group
     add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groups=ec2hosts
     with_items: ec2_info.instances
```

You can then assign roles to that group as you would normally.